# Should wife ask permission to start work

Tags: hadith, nikah, husband-wife

My wife started the business to support her family (brothers). I was not asked for permission as I thought her involvement would be minimum. I, however, keep losing jobs and she mention that she is doing it for stability which was not her intention when she started.

Now that her time is mostly spent on her phone with the logistics of the business and getting stressed and I am very tired of this way of life. I cannot focus on my career because of the environment but there is constant nagging money shortage.

At what point should I talk to my wife's parents to ask her to mend her ways or should I make a decision based on how things are going.

What is Islamic teaching on a wife who takes life-changing steps without consent from her husband?

Answer (score -1):

Husband is the master of the house. This is indicated in the below verse. Wife is obligated to take husband's permission before she starts to work.

> “They both found her lord [sayyid] (i.e. her husband) at the door”
> [Yoosuf 12:25]